# How do you split modules into individual files using ChiselStage?

Tags: chisel

I would like to split modules into files, like the old `--split-modules` flag used to do.  Passing this flag to `ChiselStage` throws an error that this is deprecated, however I cannot find any documentation on what the supported arguments to ChiselStage are.

I am executing ChiselStage as follows:

```
object GenerateAsaSec extends App {
  val chiselStage = new ChiselStage
  chiselStage.execute(Array("-X", "verilog", "--split-modules", "--target-dir", "genrtl"), Seq(ChiselGeneratorAnnotation(() => new MyModule())))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-e` or `--emit-modules` with a specific form you want to emit (`chirrtl`, `high`, `middle`, `low`, `verilog`, `mverilog`, or `sverilog`) to request that a specific emitter is run and splits all modules (or `-E`/`--emit-circuit` for an emitter that emits the circuit in one file).

The following should do what you want:

```scala
chiselStage.execute(
  Array(
    "-X", "verilog", 
    "-e", "verilog", 
    "--target-dir", "genrtl"), 
  Seq(ChiselGeneratorAnnotation(() => new MyModule()))
)
```

Tangentially, the error message there is worse than I thought. It should mention something about `-e`. Sorry about the confusion!

Anecdotally, the reason this was removed was that it was tricky to deal with a global option like `--split-modules`. Emitters are just transforms. It then became weird to have one global option that would affect all downstream transforms when a user might want a mix of file outputs produced by running a mix of transforms. E.g., the current version allows for emitting a high form circuit (`-E high`) and one-module-per-file Verilog (`-e verilog`) as arguments to the same invocation of `ChiselStage`.